# How to append nightly build date to VersionSuffix for a .NET Core 3.1 Visual Studio 2019 project using GitHub Actions?

Tags: .net-core, versioning, github-actions, dotnet-cli

I want to define my software's version number manually by hand within the source code. At least the major, minor, and patch version components (terminology taken from [Semantic Versioning 2.0.0](https://semver.org/spec/v2.0.0.html)). However, for the build metadata, and .NET's assembly revision version component, I want them to be automatically overwritten by the build server. For example, in a development environment (developers desk), the build metadata, and assembly revision version component, is always empty resp. 0 (e.g. SemVer "1.2.3", Assembly "1.2.3.0"). When the developer checks-in the code changes, the build server replaces the build metadata, and assembly revision version component, with the format `yyMMdd` (nightly build). Using the already given example, the result would be like SemVer "1.2.3+200721", and Assembly "1.2.3.200721".

The software I am developing is a **.NET Core 3.1 C#** application, written with Visual Studio 2019. Therefore, I am using the `dotnet` CLI with a single solution file, referencing several C# projects (one primary project, and several supporting libraries). For the final build/publish (only the one primary project is build), I want to overwrite the build metadata, and assembly revision version component, with the current date for automatic nightly releases as described above.

The build server is **GitHub Actions**. This is my workflow script:

```yaml
name: "Solution.sln (main)"

# Controls when the action will run. Triggers the workflow on push or
# pull request events but only for the master branch.
on:
  push:
    branches: [ "develop" ]
  pull_request:
    branches: [ "develop" ]

# A workflow run is made up of one or more jobs that can run sequentially or in
# parallel.
jobs:
  ubuntu-build:
    name: Ubuntu 20.04 build
    runs-on: ubuntu-20.04
    env:
      DOTNET_NOLOGO: true
      DOTNET_CLI_TELEMETRY_OPTOUT: true
      DOTNET_MULTILEVEL_LOOKUP: true
    steps:
      - name: Checkout source code
        uses: actions/checkout@v2
        with:
          clean: true
          fetch-depth: 1
          lfs: true
          submodules: true
      - name: Setup dotnet core cli
        uses: actions/setup-dotnet@v1
        with:
          dotnet-version: "3.1.x"
      - name: Restores NuGet packages
        run: dotnet restore Solution.sln
      - name: Builds solution assemblies
        run: dotnet build Solution.sln --configuration Release --no-restore
      - name: Tests solution assemblies
        run: dotnet test Solution.sln --configuration Release --no-build --no-restore
      - name: Publishes application
        run: dotnet publish MainApplication/MainApplication.csproj --configuration Release --no-restore --output publish/ -p:PublishReadyToRun=false -p:PublishSingleFile=false -p:PublishTrimmed=true --self-contained false -p:Version
```

I have the following within my **.csproj* files:

```xml
  <PropertyGroup>
    <VersionPrefix>1.2.3</VersionPrefix>
    <VersionSuffix></VersionSuffix>
    <Version>$(VersionPrefix)$(VersionSuffix)</Version>
    <AssemblyVersion>$(VersionPrefix).0</AssemblyVersion>
    <FileVersion>$(AssemblyVersion)</FileVersion>
    <InformationalVersion>$(Version)</InformationalVersion>
    <PackageVersion>$(Version)</PackageVersion>
  </PropertyGroup>
```

Be aware, that `VersionSuffix` may already contain information, e.g. `alpha.1` (pre-release version notation). Such information must not be overwritten, and have to persists in the final assembly. You probably noticed, that I have overwritten the default `Version` concatenation mechanics, this is because a stable release (`VersionSuffix` would be empty) version would result into a build server version like "1.2.3-+200721", which is an invalid SemVer, as "-" is the marker for the pre-release version, but there is no pre-release version content, so I have overwritten it, and have to put the "-" for pre-releases manually in `VersionSuffix`.

I am aware, that I can overwrite CSPROJ properties via the `dotnet` CLI using command line arguments like `-p:VersionSuffix=+200721`, `-p:AssemblyVersion=1.2.3.200721`.

However, the issue with this solution (exactly as described) is that the build server does not know about the already assigned version within csproj file.

**How do I extract `VersionPrefix`, and `VersionSuffix` within the GitHub Actions environment, to use them as (environment) variables in the GitHub Actions script's job steps?**

To summarize what I want to do:

- extract `VersionSuffix` (, and `VersionSuffix` if `VersionSuffix` cannot be appended but only replaced),
- (via `dotnet` CLI) append (*not* replace) to `VersionSuffix` the nightly build date (format `+yyMMdd`),
- (via `dotnet` CLI) replace `AssemblyVersion` with "$(VersionSuffix).yyMMdd".

Comment: I am interested in this Answer, too.